# when i install my apk in my phone it shows that "DO you want to install this application? It does not require any special access."

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I am trying to build an a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJjgW.png)pk (mobile application) using xamarin for detecting the outgoing calls, the functionality are working good, but the issue i am not getting displayed any permission when installing in my mobile.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xK3kjMMIREBivHGLzkvWOjNOd7IGVW8W/view?usp=sharing)   see this image  i am not getting like that

Comment: Which android version did you install? Which permissions did you want to request?

Comment: android Oreo(8.1) for process_outgoing_calls

Answer (score 1):

From android 6.0 runtime permissions are introduced and apps no longer require any special permissions during installation.

Read this [article here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions)

Many Custom ROMs or skins like MIUI have already included runtime permissions mechanism for lower android devices (below 6.0) as well

Comment: [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xK3kjMMIREBivHGLzkvWOjNOd7IGVW8W/view) see that image i am not getting like that